# Using sed and grep/egrep to search and replace

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I am using `egrep -R` followed by a regular expression containing about 10 unions, so like:
`.jpg | .png | .gif` etc. This works well, now I would like to replace all strings found with `.bmp`

I was thinking of something like

```
egrep -lR "\.jpg|\.png|\.gif" . | sed "s/some_expression/.jpg/" file_it_came_form
```

so the issue here is how do I do a similar union regular expression in `sed` and how do I tell it to save the changes to the file that it got the input from.

Comment: I found this question while searching for ways to search and replace across multiple files in a directory hierarchy.  For others in my situation, try [rpl](http://freshmeat.net/projects/rpl/).

Comment: thank you rpl works and is really easy to remember.. just rpl old_string new_string target_files.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Use this command:

```
egrep -lRZ "\.jpg|\.png|\.gif" . \
    | xargs -0 -l sed -i -e 's/\.jpg\|\.gif\|\.png/.bmp/g'
```

- **`egrep`**: find matching lines using extended regular expressions

  - `-l`: only list matching filenames
  - `-R`: search recursively through all given directories
  - `-Z`: use `\0` as record separator
  - `"\.jpg|\.png|\.gif"`: match one of the strings `".jpg"`, `".gif"` or `".png"`
  - `.`: start the search in the current directory
- **`xargs`**: execute a command with the stdin as argument

  - `-0`: use `\0` as record separator. This is important to match the `-Z` of `egrep` and to avoid being fooled by spaces and newlines in input filenames.
  - `-l`: use one line per command as parameter
- **`sed`**: the **s**tream **ed**itor

  - `-i`: replace the input file with the output without making a backup
  - `-e`: use the following argument as expression
  - `'s/\.jpg\|\.gif\|\.png/.bmp/g'`: replace all occurrences of the strings `".jpg"`, `".gif"` or `".png"` with `".bmp"`

Comment: it all works except the | in the sed part. I don't understand why though since it makes sense... the -l part of xargs was giving me errors so I took it out, could that be related?

Comment: I found that this command adds a newline to the end of all the files that it processes.

Comment: @titanumdecoy: I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour. what version of sed were you using and on which OS are you?

Comment: @DavidSchmitt: You probably want to use `sed -r` for extended regular expressions. At that point, the pattern will match what's used in egrep, and you may want to put it in a variable for reuse.

Comment: this command saved me hours of work copying header files out of my app for the library I made. This is awesome :)  Here is the command I used egrep -lRZ "\.h$" . | xargs -0 tar -cvf headers.tar | (cp headers.tar headers; cd headers; tar xf headers.tar; )

Comment: Is `-e` strictly necessary for `sed` here?

Comment: On OSX you have to provide `sed -i` with an empty file e.g.: `sed -i ''` to properly change stuff in place.

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, much as I love sed for appropriate tasks, this is definitely a task for perl -- it's truly more powerful for this kind of one-liners, especially to "write it back to where it comes from" (perl's `-i` switch does it for you, and optionally also lets you keep the old version around e.g. with a .bak appended, just use `-i.bak` instead).

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/.jpg/
```

rather than intricate work in sed (if even possible there) or awk...

Comment: sed uses -i, just like perl.

Comment: @Stobor - I swear I've had issues where the perl operation when I fed the regex replacement string did exactly what I wanted, unlike sed, even if I gave the regex option to `sed`.. I think I either forgot some flags to sed or it had limitations.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do this

```
find . -name *.xml -exec sed -i "s/4.6.0-SNAPSHOT/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/" {} \;
```

Some help regarding the above command

The find will do the find for you on the current directory indicated by `.`

`-name` the name of the file in my case its pom.xml can give wild cards.

`-exec` execute

`sed` stream editor

`-i` ignore case

`s` is for substitute

`/4.6.0.../` String to be searched

`/5.0.0.../` String to be replaced

Comment: perhaps not as powerful - but this is a lot easier for me to understand than the accepted answer

Comment: @icc97 - I agree that it's easier to understand, but I can't think of any reason why this would be less powerful.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get any of the commands on this page to work for me: the [sed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace/1169958#1169958) added a newline to the end of all the files it processed, and the [perl solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace/1169955#1169955) was unable to accept enough arguments from find.  I found this solution which works perfectly:

```
find . -type f -name '*.[hm]' -print0 
    | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/search_regex/replacement_string/g'
```

This will recurse down the current directory tree and replace `search_regex` with `replacement_string` in any files ending in `.h` or `.m`.

I have also used [rpl](http://freshmeat.net/projects/rpl/) for this purpose in the past.

Answer (score 0):

try something using a for loop

```
 for i in `egrep -lR "YOURSEARCH" .` ; do echo  $i; sed 's/f/k/' <$i >/tmp/`basename $i`; mv /tmp/`basename $i` $i; done
```

not pretty, but should do.

Comment: xargs is definitely more appropriate here.

Comment: and using the `|while read i` pattern would enable streaming and avoid length restrictions when egrep's results become too long

Answer (score 0):

My use case was I wanted to replace 
`foo:/Drive_Letter` with `foo:/bar/baz/xyz`
In my case I was able to do it with the following code.
I was in the same directory location where there were bulk of files.

```
find . -name "*.library" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/foo:\/Drive_Letter:/foo:\/bar\/baz\/xyz/g'
```

hope that helped.

UPDATE 
s|foo:/Drive_letter:|foo:/ba/baz/xyz|g

Comment: You can use other delimiters for the sed command, and doing so makes pathnames much nicer: `sed 's|foo:/Drive_letter:|foo:/ba/baz/xyz|g'`