# Change all with command line

Tags: command-line, terminal, command

I'm wondering if there is a way to change a specific word in all of the files within the /www/ directory using command line. Just looking for a faster way to change out a specific word so I don't need to open all the files manually! Thanks!

Comment: What is "terminal"? And what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Terminal is os x command line. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find /www -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' \{\} \;`

This line will replace foo with bar every time foo occurs in any file in `/www`.  Be very sure you know what's under `/www` and what the replacement would do to those files before running it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a [grep-sed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace) to find and replace, if you are on a Mac (and referring to the Mac's Terminal app).