# How to remove all NSLog statements in a file using a regular expression with the Xcode Find & Replace option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, ios4

I have an [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) project which has lots of [NSLog](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog) statementS.

I have to submit my app to get approval from Apple, and I would like to remove all NSLog statementS which I had used for debugging.

I want to remove only NSLog statements.

Comment: but if we use the regular expression in xcode find & replace by selecting regular expression textbox in that,we can select all the NSlog statements.but i want to know that how to specify regular expression for NSLog(...);.

Comment: Your question is still not clear can you please post some code which can make us understand better?

Comment: `NSLog\(.*\);\n$`? But it f*** up indention.

Comment: hey PARTH ankit is right by through this we can delete all NSLog statements in out project .any way thanku for care

Comment: Have a look at this answer here...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12382047/1463604

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Xcode, you can use Find and Replace and provide a regular expression something like:

```
NSLog.*;
```

Answer (score 8):

Put this in your prefix header......

```
   #ifndef __OPTIMIZE__

    #    define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)

      #else

     #    define NSLog(...) {}

      #endif
```

Comment: hey buddy thanks.but NSLog.*;
this one is very handy.anyway thanks for ur answer

Comment: This method is MUCH more useful than NSLog.*; because I can keep all my logs but suppress their output for the distribution binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your NSLog statements using [sed and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace). The basic idea is to `grep` all lines containing NSLog statements and then delete them using `sed`.

Using sed and grep might be new to you, but it's very helpful in the long run!

Here's some code I think *should* work, but backup your work first:
`grep -Ev 'NSLog'`.

Comment: Dear @ryyst, I would not appreciate a technique that is irreversible & backup dependent.