# Can NSLog be disabled from appearing in device's console?

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I have a builded application that is running on device. I open device's console view in XCode's Organizer window. I assume (for the sake of this question) that NSLog(@"Some string") gets called.

Is there any way, may be an option in device, or application's settings, that would disable this log from appearing in console?

Edit: I'm not interested in replacing NSLog by other solution that can achieve this effect. The purpose of this question is to fully understand NSLog's functionality.

Comment: Search google for Objective-C DLog.

Comment: @Wain this would be useful if the purpose of my question was to achieve this effect — hide NSLogs from console. It's not.

Comment: That's what it does. NSLog itself doesn't offer any options so you need some wrapper around it so you can disable logs on demand or for your release build.

Comment: I don't want to disable logs. I want to understand how they could, theoretically, be disabled, so I would understand why don't they show up when they should.

Comment: There is no setting (as far as I know) that disables NSLog. But the logs ultimately are printed to stderr, so closing or redirecting stderr would have such an effect, compare trojanfoe's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to @MartinR for encouraging me to pull my finger out on this answer and to correctly identify that you cannot just close stdout/stderr, as the next `open()` will re-use those file descriptors, but to redirect stdout/stderr to the infamous `/dev/null`).

logControl.h:

```
#pragma once

extern void stopLogging();
extern void startLogging();
```

logControl.c:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static int loggingStopped = 0;
static int oldStdout = -1;
static int oldStderr = -1;

void stopLogging() {
    if (!loggingStopped) {
        oldStdout = dup(1);
        oldStderr = dup(2);

        int devNull = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        dup2(devNull, 1);
        dup2(devNull, 2);
        close(devNull);

        loggingStopped = 1;
    }
}

void startLogging() {
    if (loggingStopped && oldStdout >= 0 && oldStderr >= 0) {
        dup2(oldStdout, 1);
        close(oldStdout);
        oldStdout = -1;

        dup2(oldStderr, 2);
        close(oldStderr);
        oldStderr = -1;

        loggingStopped = 0;
    }
}
```

This works at *runtime*, not *compile time*, which I believe is what you are asking.  Simply call `stopLogging()` or `startLogging()` as required.

NOTE: There is no error-checking to speak of, so that could be improved perhaps.

Comment: Better use dup2() to "redirect" stderr to /dev/null. Otherwise the next file opened will reuse these file descriptors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12611692/1187415 for an example.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I think you're right.  You'd have to save the old stdout and stderr as well, in case you wanted to re-open it.  Doesn't matter - this answer isn't well-liked anyway ;-)

Comment: The problem might be that it is unclear (and misunderstood by some people) what answer the OP expects. To me yours seems to come closest to a possible answer.

Comment: @MartinR OK, I'll make some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line given below in your .pch file in Xcode.

```
   #define NSLog(...)
```

It will disable all NSLogs.

for more alternatives see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732333/how-do-i-disable-nslog)

Answer (score 0):

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

//Simulator

#else

// Device
#define NSLog
#endif
```

Add this in your **.pch** file this will disable `NSLog` only for device alone not for simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to .pch file

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#   define NSLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

And in Build Settings, search "Preprocessor Macros" and remove "DEBUG=1" written in it.

and Thats it, you will not see any logs in your console now.