# using sed and grep to search and replace (skipping .svn or .git)

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm [using sed and grep to search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace) boost::shared_ptr with std::shared_ptr. How do I keep `egrep` out of `.svn`. Its leading to local corruptions:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: E155017: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155017: Working copy text base is corrupt
svn: E200014: Checksum mismatch for text base of '/home/jeffrey/owasp-esapi-cplusplus/doc/html/_codec_8cpp_source.html':
   expected:  09ead67f10a06a392ec41455179da560
     actual:  310ceca1a9c721b40db494f62854d2df
```

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) instead of `grep` to search files. It takes the same basic options as `grep`.

It will skip `.svn`, `.git`... dirs & binaries by default.

Example :

```
ack -rl --print0 "pattern" . | xargs -0 -l sed -i 's/pattern/other_pattern/g'
```

So finally :

```
ack -rl --print0 "boost::shared_ptr" . |
    xargs -0 -l sed -i 's/boost::shared_ptr/std::shared_ptr/g'
```

Comment: xargs -l is deprecated. -L 1 is POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Try `find` with `xargs`

```
find /path/to/basedir -name .svn -prune -o -iname '*.h' -print0 , -iname '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/boost::shared_ptr/std::shared_ptr/g'
```