# Mass Updates To Classes In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

We have a library of Hibernate model objects that was generated by Hibernate Tools by a now-departed developer. Unfortunately, the results don't meet our team naming standards.

The issue I'm mostly concerned with is that the generated objects implement "java.io.Serializable", instead of having an import for Serializable.

At this point it's impossible to regenerate these objects. Is there a was to do some sort of mass update in Eclipse? A cntrl-shift-O does no good.

Answer (score 3):

As I know what equipment you are using, I dont think you will want to do this in eclipse unless you have updated you computer recently.

Being somewhat familiar with what you are using and the applications you should have on your system.  You are going to wanna use Notepad++ and a Search "Find in Files".  Two searches should do it one to remove implements XYZ and replace it with "" and another to to find a common import statement and add your import XYZ.

Let me know if you have any questions.  I do believe you have my twitter and phone number.

All that being said if you want to be stubborn and do a find and replace for a large amount of files in eclipse on your memory challenged system.  CTRL+h has a file search option where you can accomplish the replaces mentioned above in eclipse.

Comment: Come on, tell us what is going on! Yeaz pleaz!

Comment: Is this the guy mentioned in OP's post who used to work for the company? I have the strangest feeling that's the reason he's so vehemently familiar with the OP's company proceedings...

Comment: Yes, he's familiar with some of my team's procedures and standards, but many have changed since his departure. Also, his knowledge of our hardware baseline is slightly out of date as well.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?  You could also try this link, which may work in cygwin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace