# How to replace line number delimiter in grep output

Tags: grep, delimiter

I am doing:

```
egrep -e "String" -in -A 2 file1.log
```

I am getting output as

```
111:some text
112-some text
113-some text
```

How to replace ^'[0-9]{1,9}-' to ^'[0-9]{1,9}:' for each line number at start of each line in a file? So that it will look like:

```
111:some text
112:some text
113:some text
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace, hope it helps!

Comment: I tried but not worked. I am looking solution like this  egrep -e "String" -in -A 2 file1.log | sed 's/^'[0-9]{1,9}-'/^'[0-9]{1,9}:'/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output into `sed`. This works here:

```
grep ... | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)-/\1:/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thor :) , yes its working but it also deleting group separators '--'. Just as workaround I changed group separators as '==' using this option of grep "--group-separator=="

Comment: @ypp: Yes I noticed that and changed the pattern to use the `\+` quantifier instead of `*`.